# How to manipulate a variable before sending to servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I've got a JSP page which contains a textbox, wrapped in a form.  This form's action is set to a servlet.

I would like to manipulate the string (from the user's input in the textbox) before it is sent to the servlet, thus basically carrying out a simple `request.setParameter` call from the JSP to the servlet.  Can this be done?  If so how can I obtain the textbox's value in the JSP?

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="txtUsername"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what manipulation you want to do, may be I can suggest better way

Comment: I need to send a hashed version of the username, and it's important that the hashing does not take place in the servlet.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: You already accepted the answer so I assume it resolved your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using JSP code.
Remember, a JSP is processed, outputting its contents to the browser; that's where the JSP's request/response cycle ends.

Your options are:

1. Using JavaScript.
2. Using a Filter: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Call a Javascript function on `submit` e.g. below:

```
  function fnSubmit(){
     document.getElementById("txtUsername").value = "new Value";
     document.forms[0].submit();
  }
```